# Network code stopping with SIGPIPE

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sigpipe

I am developing in iOS.

The App call the function in library , and send the packet via wifi.

When the App is running , I push the power button(not home button) on iPhone 5C and push again to open it. But it crash...

And it did not show which line is error , it only show the error like the following picture:

[image]

How to analyse this crash log via above picture?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What function in what library?

Comment: type `bt` in console you will see more detailed back trace

Comment: @siemian Sorry...Can you explain more detail ? Where should I type `bt` ?

Comment: @Martin have you enabled breakpoints for all exceptions?

Comment: @Martin, the console in the bottom of xcode

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Apple, in [Avoiding Common Networking Mistakes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/CommonPitfalls/CommonPitfalls.html), you need to handle or disable `SIGPIPE`:

> **Use POSIX sockets efficiently (if at all).**
>
> If you are using POSIX sockets directly:
>
> - Handle or disable SIGPIPE.
>
> When a connection closes, by default, your
>   process receives a `SIGPIPE` signal. If your program does not handle or
>   ignore this signal, your program will quit immediately. You can handle
>   this in one of two ways:
>
> Ignore the signal globally with the following line of code:
>
> ```
> signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
> ```
>
> Tell the socket not to send the signal in
>   the first place with the following lines of code (substituting the
>   variable containing your socket in place of `sock`):
>
> ```
> int value = 1;
> setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, &value, sizeof(value));
> ```
>
> For maximum compatibility, you should set this flag on each incoming
>   socket immediately after calling accept in addition to setting the
>   flag on the listening socket itself.

Comment: I'll just mention that I've experienced a crash exactly like the one in the OP's picture despite having "signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)" in my program. I think it happened after my app had been suspended, or at least having been put in background, and then being activated again. Anyway now I've added the second technique as well, and have crossed my fingers.